# SQL Constraints Confusion

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

I'm in a bit of a mix right now, I have a Table called Avatars, which has a foreign key called Family. Now, in the family table, I have two Foreign Keys called Mother and Father - Now this is the confusing bit, in both the Mother and Father Tables, there is a Foreign key called Avatar_ID which is of course the Primary Key to the Avatars table. I'm not sure if that's even allowed in SQL PLUS.

Whenever I try and enter the tables 'Family, Mother or Father', I keep getting the error:ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SG304.FK_FATHER_ID) violated - parent key not found.

Is there any way around this? Or will I have to change my code completely? A sample of the code is below.

```
CREATE TABLE Avatars (
Avatar_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Avatar_Name VARCHAR(30),
AvA_DOB DATE,
Age VARCHAR(30),
Gender VARCHAR(30),
Strength_Indicated INT,
Hoard INT,
Avatar_Level VARCHAR(30),
Skill VARCHAR(30),
Original_Owner VARCHAR(30),
Family_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Species_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Inventory_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Weapon_ID VARCHAR(10),
Player_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Avatar_ID));

CREATE TABLE Family (
Family_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Mother_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Father_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
primary key(Family_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Mother (
Mother_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Avatar_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
primary key(Mother_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Father (
Father_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Avatar_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
primary key(Father_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE Avatars
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Family_ID
FOREIGN KEY (Family_ID)
REFERENCES Family(Family_ID);

ALTER TABLE Family
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Mother_ID
FOREIGN KEY (Mother_ID)
REFERENCES Mother(Mother_ID);

ALTER TABLE Family
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Father_ID
FOREIGN KEY (Father_ID)
REFERENCES Father(Father_ID);

ALTER TABLE Father
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Avatar_ID
FOREIGN KEY (Avatar_ID)
REFERENCES Avatars(Avatar_ID);

ALTER TABLE Mother
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Avatars_ID
FOREIGN KEY (Avatar_ID)
REFERENCES Avatars(Avatar_ID);

INSERT INTO Avatars (Avatar_ID,Avatar_Name,AvA_DOB,Age,Gender,Strength_Indicated,Hoard,Avatar_Level, Skill, Original_Owner, Family_ID,Species_ID,Inventory_ID,Player_ID) VALUES
('Ava01','Verda','20-JAN-2014','1 year 2 months','Female','100','20','Master','Leader',' - ',' - ','DRA1','MasterInventory','Player07');
```

Thanks in advance for any help given! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign key refers to a record in parent table. In your `INSERT` statement you are inserting value `' - '` into a column `parent_id`. In this error message oracle informs you that there is no record with value `' - '` in a column `family_id` of a table `family`. As I can understand, you are trying to use `' - '` as 'absence of value'. There is special value for that - [NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)). So you need to write your statement as:

```
INSERT INTO Avatars (Avatar_ID, Avatar_Name, AvA_DOB, 
   Age, Gender, Strength_Indicated, Hoard, Avatar_Level, Skill, 
   Original_Owner, Family_ID, Species_ID, Inventory_ID, Player_ID) 
VALUES ('Ava01', 'Verda', '20-JAN-2014', '1 year 2 months' ,'Female', 
   '100', '20', 'Master', 'Leader', NULL, NULL, 'DRA1', 
   'MasterInventory', 'Player07');
```

Also I can recommend some changes to your schema. First of all, use `number` data type for primary keys - it allows you to use [sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11792) to generate unique values. Also, I don't know details of the problem, but "family relations" in your tables look a bit complicated. You can describe it in a single table:

```
create table family_tree (
  person_id number primary key,
  father_id number,
  mother_id number,
  sex char(1),
  name varchar2(50),
  family_name varchar2(50));

add constraint fk_mother_id foreign key (mother_id) 
references family_tree (person_id);   

add constraint fk_father_id foreign key (father_id) 
references family_tree (person_id);
```

Comment: Thank-you! I redid my coding, it was just really confusing. Thanks for the recommendation, I have used that! (: